# c++ templated methods

Tags: java, templates, generics, methods

How are templated methods implemented in C++?

I'm thinking about implementing templates in the JVM and have got a possible implementation thought out for templated classes, but am unsure on methods.

If, for example, you did:

```
class Test
{
    public static boolean isIterable<T>(T variable)
    {
        return T instanceof Iterable;
    }
}

System.out.println(Test.isIterable(new int[] { 0 }));
```

Would I create a version of `Test` that replied to `int[]`? (In my implementation, the class would be named as such: `$g$Test$A_Java_lang_int`)

Please ignore any problems with generics (such as only requiring boxed objects), as I intend to remove them.

I plan on creating these resolved templates dynamically, and keeping track of the number of references so I can remove them if they are not used. I believe this is how .Net manages it, although I'd be happy to be wrong here!

Comment: Meaning you want to implement something using the name-mangling route instead of using type erasure?

Comment: This is part of another language implementation on top of the JVM, so the name mangling would not be visible, and the classes would be loaded in a custom classloader, but yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I create a version of Test that replied to `int[]`?

Essentially, yes. Templates in C++ are purely a compile-time mechanism that uses a (glorified) macro mechanism to generate code based on a *template* for each type with which it’s instantiated.

(C++ actually does a lot more due to the possibility of specialisation but this is the gist of it.)

Comment: Specialisation such as giving a constant instead of a Type? or am I missing something?

Comment: @Darkzaelus No, specialisation as in providing a special implementation for a concrete (or a “more specialised”) type, e.g. a general implementation for enumerables, and a special one for arrays, and the compiler decides which implementation to use when invoked with a template argument.

Comment: I see, that's really quite powerful! It sounds a bit like Haskall's call patterns specialisation. I think I'll leave this feature out of my language as I have pattern matching in by default

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to do this staticly by generating the classes.  You might find http://trove.starlight-systems.com/ interesting as it has a templating approach to generating its primitive collections. e.g. TintLongHashMap  This doesn't rely on any language features.

I would suggest you work out how to do this staticly before trying to do it dynamicly which is much harder.

Comment: In terms of problems with doing it dynamically, I plan on slightly extending the class file format with placeholders for generic types (like how .Net) manages it. Then I plan to load it in with BCEL, create a resolved version, load it in with a custom classloader and keep track of references to it. Interesting concept to code, but for my programming language, I would need it.

Comment: Like I said, if you can determine the types needed staticly, it would be much simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really. The classes will be loaded dynamically based on a web server request.

Comment: Are you sure you are not going to alot of effort for something which will make a very minor difference.  Using a templated class with primitives can save micro-seconds, but if you have a web server request which might have a 20 ms network delay, will it really matter?

Comment: This is mainly a way of really saving Java generics. Since this language will be built on multiple VMs and other languages (Trying to implement templates in PHP is interesting!), I would like to emulate something like how C++ or C# manages them. Plus quite a bit of this is exercise for me at the moment!

Comment: As an exercise, I agree its an interesting problem. You just need to be clear in your own mind what you hope to achieve. ;)

Comment: I hope I am, Peter! Give me a couple of years and I'll tell you how I got on!

Comment: Perhaps you can think of ways to do it in less time. ;)

Comment: oh i'm talking about the whole of my language! hopefully the custom classloader shouldn't be too much trouble...

Comment: Perhaps you could write up all the improvements you are looking to make compared with existing languages and get feedback on what you should implement first.

Comment: my first implementation I plan to be the classic hello world! and then it's pretty much scala on steroids, i'm fairly ambitious, but i've almost gotten the spec written and the parser is started